# Alternatives to Mamp Pro – which works with Craft CMS

Tags: craft3, mysql, mamp

I've been a long time user of Mamp Pro, but I'm getting an error using v3 with Craft3, due to needing to update to Mamp Pro 4, however after some hrs trying to update to Mamp 4, I can't get mySQL to start and therefore wondered what alternatives to Mamp other devs use – which isn't overly complex?

Comment: I've literally just moved from Mamp 3 to 4 in the last hour. All seems fine. 
Did you run the Mysql upgrade from Mamp 4's Tools menu?

Comment: I can't get that far – MySQL won't start and I the whole interface (all buttons) is non-clickable

Comment: I got Mamp Pro 4 to work in the end, I have to 'quit & save' to save settings but I can live with that – to retain familiarity of the Mamp gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you check out [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet).

Here's an article on it that may be useful to you as well: [Running Craft CMS 3 on Laravel Valet](https://medium.com/@jalendport/running-craft-cms-3-on-laravel-valet-6df61e5193fd)

Comment: @user2569 let me know if you have any issues getting setup! (I'm the author of the article Andrew linked to and I'd be more than happy to answer any questions or help you troubleshoot.)

Comment: Thanks for that, got Mamp pro 4 working for now but will be giving valet a try soon as the docs/features look very appealing!